# Vertical position fixed

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I need to fix a div/image 16 pixels from top of the window... The content needs to scroll, but the div/image can't scroll... My main problem is that it can't be fixed with the position attribute because i need it to scroll horizontally. and with position:fixed it locks both vertically and horizontally...
I've already tried overflow (overflow-y: hidden doesn't work) and can't get any results...
 Is there any way to say that the div/image should lock it's vertically movement on that place? any ideas?

Comment: What did you produced so far ? Add your HTML/CSS code in the question.

Comment: @Zeratops For this case my code won't help... I just need to know if is possible to lock a div vertically and don't lock it horizontally. And if so, how ca i do it... I have a div (the one that i need to lock) inside another div (site wrap) with position: relative...

Comment: Not with `position:fixed` as it's fixed in relation to the *viewport* not any other DOM elements. I suspect that a Javascript solution is required,

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to fix the div vertically, but allow the image to scroll horizontally as @Paulie_D suggests, you can try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bnu4rhop/

This depends on a `position: fixed` with an accompanying javascript function that adjusts the `left` css value.

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $('#my_div').css({left: -$(window).scrollLeft()})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just position:absolute your div and when the user is scrolling
adjust the top value with javascript :

```
 $(window).scrollTop() + 16;
```

If you want to center horizontally your div :

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -(You div width / 2);
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have many experience with javascript... can you please tell how do i connect the script with the div (my div name is #baar)
thank you very much